# How to use temporary table in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to read data from a excel file store it in temporary table (devices temp table) and after all data is copied in to this temporary table. These records are updated in actual table(userDevices) and previous enteries need to be removed.

I have used EF6 in my project. and accordingly I have mapped entity "Device" with the "userDevices" table. how will I leverage entity framework to insert data in temp table and then replace it in actual table.

Is stored proc is the only option? Or  can I utilize EF for the same?

Comment: Can't you read excel file and save data in memory like a DataTable or List, then map this memory item to you Device table?

Comment: No. The requirement is to save it in temp table first. as data would be very large. Moreover I need to put all in transaction

Comment: If your temporary table has to store data, then why can't it be a table that is always present, its data could be treated as temporary. Does structure (no and types of column) change ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to use temp tables is to have their creation, manipulation, insertion and ultimately data extraction all done in stored procedures. Once those are setup, then `EF` can call and utilize them.

As an aside `EF` does not browse the `tempDb` schema when it generates the table mappings; hence any temp table regardless of session (`#` vs `##`) status cannot be used; due to the nature of temp tables themselves.